# FIWARE Lab Store widget list errors and publishing

Tags: fiware-wirecloud

lately the FIWARE Lab store doesn't seem to work for me. The first page with Top Rated and Latest offerings loads ok, but after clicking on widgets/mashups tab, it produces an error window:

```
get() returned more than one Purchase -- it returned 2! Lookup parameters
were {'customer': <django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject object at
0x7fd9e41a3750>, 'organization_owned': False, 'offering': <Offering: EntityService>}
```

Also, when trying to publish a widget, after choosing to upload to the FIWARE Lab Store, the POST request to https://mashup.lab.fiware.org/api/markets/publish fails with code 502 and the following response:

```
{"description": "Something went wrong (see details for more info)",
"details": {"FIWARE Lab": "Unexpected response from Store"}}
```

I know that some software components have been updated lately so I understand that this might be a transitional bug. Thanks for your help if you can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed, that was a temporal problem. You should be able to use the Store portal again.

Anyway, StackOverflow is for asking questions related to programming (visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more info), so it's better to use the contact info published on the [FIWARE catalogue](https://catalogue.fiware.org) or the `fiware-lab-help@lists.fiware.org` for this kind of questions/support.